# Not able to get specific object from a json response using python

Tags: python, json, foursquare

I have the following as part of a function to extract some info from a json response (at the bottom you can find a portion of it), and is working fine. But......

```
venues_list=[]

url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id={}&client_secret={}&ll={},{}&v={}&categoryId={}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, lat, lng, VERSION, search_categoryId, radius, LIMIT)

results = requests.get(url).json()["response"]['venues']

venues_list.append([(
            v['name'], 
            v['location']['lat'], 
            v['location']['lng'],  
            v['categories'][0]['name'],
            v['id']) for v in results])
```

To the mix of objects I'm retrieving from the json file, i want to add:

**v['location']['postalCode']**

But is not working. I get a **KeyError: 'postalCode'**

If I do:

**v['location']['distance']**

**v['location']['country']**

**v['location']['formattedAddress']**

It works. I get no error.

These don't work either:

**v['location']['cc']**

**v['location']['city']**

I get the same **KeyError: 'cc'** , **KeyError: 'city'**

Is there something I'm missing? Can you help me understand why it behaves this way?

```
[{'id': '4ad4c061f964a52099f720e3',
  'name': 'Live Organic Food Bar',
  'location': {'address': '264 Dupont Street',
   'lat': 43.67505287052667,
   'lng': -79.40671518307245,
   'labeledLatLngs': [{'label': 'display',
     'lat': 43.67505287052667,
     'lng': -79.40671518307245}],
   'distance': 273,
   'postalCode': 'M5R 1V7',
   'cc': 'CA',
   'city': 'Toronto',
   'state': 'ON',
   'country': 'Canada',
   'formattedAddress': ['264 Dupont Street', 'Toronto ON M5R 1V7', 'Canada']},
  'categories': [{'id': '4bf58dd8d48988d1d3941735',
    'name': 'Vegetarian / Vegan Restaurant',
    'pluralName': 'Vegetarian / Vegan Restaurants',
    'shortName': 'Vegetarian / Vegan',
    'icon': {'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/food/vegetarian_',
     'suffix': '.png'},
    'primary': True}],
  'referralId': 'v-1591407049',
  'hasPerk': False},
```

Comment: The excerpt you posted from the JSON file does indeed include all of those keys.  But are you sure that *every single item in the file* has them?  You may need to program a bit more defensively to handle such possibilities - `v['location'].get('postalCode', '')` for example (you can put whatever you want as the value to show for a missing code in place of the final `''`).

Comment: Oh I see now. Yes, you are right. Not every item has that key. I also see where my confusion started. Because raw json can be a bit cumbersome to look at, to take a first glance at it, I do a **json_normalize(results)** . In that dataframe format, I was able to see some NaN under some fields, so I was thinking the key was there, but the value of it was NaN. So i was expecting some NaN when parsing the json response. Anyway, perfect! I tried what you recommended and it worked. Thanks alot! @jasonharper